# Translate from get_ipython().magic(u'R ...') to simple r2py commands

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have a Python script (converted from an IPython Notebook) with

```
def train_mod_inR():
   get_ipython().magic(u'R -i myinput')
   get_ipython().magic(u'R -o res res <- Rfunction(myinput)')
   return res
```

I am trying to just run the script using Python without any of the magic, so I am using rpy2.  Does anyone know any easy way to translate the function above so it just works with standard rpy2.  E.g., is it:

```
def train_mod_inR()
   r2py.robjects('-i myinput')
   r2py.robjects('-o res res <- Rfunction(myinput)')
   return res
```

In fact, does anyone have a good workaround for this in general?  I have a feeling this will require a bit more than what I've shown - is there any command in r2py directly that will allow us to interpret R like is being done by the magic command?

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close.

An exact translation of what is happening in the magic would be 
(NOTE: the object "converter" is defined is the next code block to break down what is happening, just assume that it is just an rpy2 converter for now):

```
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

# Take the Python object known as "myinput", pass it to R
# (going through the rpy2 conversion layer), and make it known to R
# as "myinput".
with localconverter(converter) as cv: 
    r2py.robjects.globalenv['myinput'] = myinput
# Run the R function known (to R) as "Rfunction", using the object known
# to R as "myinput" as the argument. Make the resulting object known to
# as "res".
r2py.robjects('res <- Rfunction(myinput)')
# Take the R objects "res", pass it to Python (going through the rpy2
# conversion layer), and make it known to Python as "res".
with localconverter(converter) as cv:
    res = r2py.robjects.globalenv['res']
```

The conversion can be customized in the R magic (https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.1.x/html/interactive.html#module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic), but assuming that you are using the current default it would be (testing whether `numpy` or `pandas` are installed is left as an exercise for the reader):

```
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import Converter
converter = Converter('ipython conversion')
if has_numpy:
    from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri
    converter += numpy2ri.converter
if has_pandas:
    from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
    converter += pandas2ri.converter
```

Note that conversion can be an expensive step (for example, there is no C-level mapping between R and Python for arrays of strings so they have to be copied over a loop), and depending on how that R result is used elsewhere in the code you may want to go for a lighter conversion (or no conversion).

### Additional comment

Now this is when one want exactly replicate what is happening in an "R magic" cell in jupyter. The core part is the execution of the cell, that is the evaluation of the string:

```
r2py.robjects('res <- Rfunction(myinput)')
```

The evaluation of that string can be moved to Python, progressively or all at one. In this case only the latter is possible because there is only one function call. The function known to R as "Rfunction" can be mapped to a Python object that is callable:

```
rfunction = r2py.robjects('Rfunction')
```

If you are only interested in having `res` in Python, the creations of symbols `myinput` and `res` in R's `globalenv` might no longer be necessary and the whole can be shortened to:

```
with localconverter(converter) as cv:
    res = rfunction(myinput)
```